# iOS11 MPMusicPlayerController's nowPlayingItem method stuck

Tags: ios11, apple-music

Did anybody experience MPMusicPlayerController's nowPlayingItem method being stuck after iOS 11 upgrade? It gets SIGSTOP eventually after couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  When my MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification is called, the MPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem is usually nil-- but only when playing a song from Apple Music (even if the song has already been downloaded to the device).

My workaround is to manually call my MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification method again after one second.  By then, the MPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem is usually non-nil.

Of course, this makes my UI look quite unresponsive and sluggish.